# Values are undefined when trying to export an object form an array by element's index in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Initially I have an empty array inside of the file, but during the code execution I get data from the database and push the data to an array. My code looks like this:

items.js

```
const items = [];

const init = (connection) => {
  return connection.collection('collectionName')
    .aggregate([{
      ....
    
    }])
    .toArray()
    .then(result => {
      items.push(...result);
      return result;
    });     
};

module.exports = {
  init,
  all: items,
  item1: items[0],
  item2: roles[1],
};
```

And when I try to import all, item1 and item2 using require in a different file like this:

```
const { all, item1, item2 } = require('../data/items');
```

I get the array with object as all, but get undefined for item1 and item 2.
I can't seem to understand what the issue is. I know I can use an anonumous function when exporting and get the data this way, but I would rather do it by trying to access the data from an array by element's index. All the help is much apprecieted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the array with object as all

Given that code, you shouldn't. Presumably you call `init` at some point though.

> but get undefined for item1 and item 2. I can't seem to understand what the issue is.

At the time you read `items[0]` to assign it to the object you are exporting, the asynchronous function hasn't completed so the array is still an empty array.

You *could* replace `item1` with a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) that gets the *current* value of `items[0]` at the time you try to *read* the `item1` property, but that would be likely to still land you with race conditions.

The better solution is probably to export a **promise** that evaluates as the object once the fetch is complete.

Obviously you will then need to use `then()` or `await` on the exported value. You won't get the object directly from the `import`.

```
const init = async (connection) => {
    const items = await connection.collection('collectionName')
    .aggregate([{
      ....
    
    }])
    .toArray()
    return {
        all: items,
        item1: items[0],
        item2: roles[1], // whatever roles is
    }
};

module.exports = init();
```

and

```
const promise = require('../data/items');
const { all, item1, item2 } = await promise;
```

Comment: I see your point, unfortunately your approce won't work how I need it to work, because when I'm importing item1 for example, I need to use it like so: 

`$setOnInsert: {
 item: item1.name]
}`

I will probably have to use a getter, but thank you anyway, helped me understand the issue